# Hover and onmouseover not working with newly created DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css, game-development

I've got an inventory for items in my javascript game.

I'm trying to make it so that when you mouseover an inventory item it shows a text overlay description of the item.

My idea was to append a div with the mouseover "reveal()" function once the item is added to the inventory but for some reason its not working. It works with the item text being ::before or ::after the div but i cant seem to get a text overlay of the item image even when playing around with the Z-Index.etc

I've tried a simple :hover in CSS but couldnt get it to work that way either.

I can "spawn" the item with the text on top from the start i just cant seem to get it so that the text only appears on a mouse over.

Hopefully i have explained it in a way that makes sense:

```js
const textElement = document.getElementById('text');
const imgElement = document.getElementById('room-image');
const optionButtonsElement = document.getElementById('option-buttons');
const button3 = document.getElementById('TEST');
const inventory = document.getElementById('inventory');
const itemContainer = document.getElementById('imageContainer');
const itemText = document.getElementById('itemtext');
let textArrayIteration = 1


function reveal() {
  itemText.classList.toggle('on');

}

//ADDING OBJECT VALUE TO INVENTORY///
function pullValue() {
  var node = document.createElement("P");
  var textNodeItems = Object.values(items);
  var textNode = (document.createTextNode(textNodeItems));
  node.appendChild(textNode);
  document.getElementById("inventory").appendChild(node);

  //ASSIGNING THE IMAGE AND DIVS FOR THE ITEM//

  if (inventory.innerHTML.indexOf("test") !== -1) {
    var a = document.createElement("div")
    a.setAttribute("id", "Div1");
    var iconUrl = document.createElement("img");
    iconUrl.src = "test.jpg";
    a.appendChild(itemText);
    a.appendChild(iconUrl);
    inventory.appendChild(a);
    node.style.display = "none";

  }
```

```css
.itemtext-on {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 200;
}

.itemtext {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  font-size: 80px;
  top: 50px;
  color: red;
  z-index: 200;
}
```

```html
<div id="itemtext" class="itemtext" onmouseover="reveal()">test</div>
```

Comment: Try change ```z-index```

Comment: your hover just toggles a classname `on` which you don't have defined. I don't see what overlay you're expecting.

Comment: the class `on` isn't defined, and hence nothing happens when you toggle that class on your div

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the class `on`.
I see that you have defined `.itemtext-on`.
If this is a typo, then change it to `.itemtext.on` and it should work.